# I got No route matches {:controller=>"refinery/refinery/admin/dashboard"} error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

when i hit the url in my local host:
http://localhost:3000/refinery/events
it gets me error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"refinery/refinery/admin/dashboard"}
```

When I go through with rake routes :

```
events_events GET     /events(.:format)                             refinery/events/events#index

 events_event GET     /events/:id(.:format)                         refinery/events/events#show

pdate_positions_events_admin_events POST    /refinery/events/update_positions(.:format)   refinery/events/admin/events#update_positions

events_admin_events GET     /refinery/events(.:format)                    refinery/events/admin/events#index

POST    /refinery/events(.:format)                    refinery/events/admin/events#create

new_events_admin_event GET     /refinery/events/new(.:format)                refinery/events/admin/events#new

edit_events_admin_event GET     /refinery/events/:id/edit(.:format)           refinery/events/admin/events#edit

events_admin_event PUT     /refinery/events/:id(.:format)                refinery/events/admin/events#update

DELETE  /refinery/events/:id(.:format)                refinery/events/admin/events#destroy
```

As I am using the Refinery CMS so there are one routes.rb file in config and also in vendor/extension/ directory.
So how actually they communicate and work it out above ?

Comment: Please post your routes.rb code

Comment: please think to format your code instead other doing to you

Answer (score 3):

You must use resources properly while adding routes . There are two resources which is same .
events and events .

The other problem in this example is sometime GET events understand event id and some times admin in the place of id.

It creates conflict in your route .

Get event/:id and 
Get event/admin is creating issue.

Please use rest full routes way, collections and members , name space for admin part so that your code will be more modular.

Comment: <code>In my main route file contanis ,                                           mount Refinery::Core::Engine, :at => '/'                                 And the event engine route file contains :                             Refinery::Core::Engine.routes.draw do
#Front route
  namespace :events do
    resources :events, :path => '', :only => [:index, :show]
  end
#Admin route
  namespace :events, :path => '' do
    namespace :admin, :path => 'refinery' do
      resources :events, :except => :show do
        collection do
         post :update_positions
        end
    end
  end
end
end</code>

Comment: Could you please post your routes.rb in question and edit it?